# I downloaded a D3 visual, but when I open the html document, it doesn't work

Tags: d3.js

I downloaded the zip file here: http://romsson.github.io/dragit/

Then, I unzipped it and opened the nations.html file. Why does it not work for me? Do I need to call something else to have the visual run? Thank you.

Comment: double clicking opens it in a file protocol, which in my experience might not always work. Try launching these from a web server (e.g. using python's `SimpleHTTPServer` module)

Comment: Wow, that worked! Thank you. I'm trying to host this visual on Google Cloud. Does that mean I have to use appengine to see this visual and not just store it as an html file in a bucket?